# iOS fast image difference comparison

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, augmented-reality, vdsp

Im looking for a fast way to compare two frames of video, and decide if a lot has changed between them. This will be used to decide if I should send a request to image recognition service over `REST`, so I don't want to keep sending them, until there might be some different results. Something similar is doing `Vuforia SDK`. Im starting with a `Framebuffer` from `ARKit`, and I have it scaled to 640:480 and converted to `RGB888 vBuffer_image`. It could compare just few points, but it needs to find out if difference is significant nicely.
I started by calculating difference between few points using `vDSP` functions, but this has a disadvantage - if I move camera even very slightly to left/right, then the same points have different portions of image, and the calculated difference is high, even if nothing really changed much.
I was thinking about using `histograms`, but I didn't test this approach yet.
What would be the best solution for this? It needs to be fast, it can compare just smaller version of image, etc.

I have tested another approach using `VNFeaturePointObservation` from `Vision`. This works a lot better, but Im afraid it might be more CPU demanding. I need to test this on some older devices. Anyway, this is a part of code that works nicely. If someone could suggest some better approach to test, please let know:

```
    private var lastScanningImageFingerprint: VNFeaturePrintObservation?
    
    // Returns true if these are different enough
    private func compareScanningImages(current: VNFeaturePrintObservation, last: VNFeaturePrintObservation?) -> Bool {
        guard let last = last else { return true }
        var distance = Float(0)
        try! last.computeDistance(&distance, to: current)
        print(distance)
        return distance > 10
    }
    
    // After scanning is done, subclass should prepare suggestedTargets array.
    private func performScanningIfNeeded(_ sender: Timer) {
        guard !scanningInProgress else { return } // Wait for previous scanning to finish
        guard let vImageBuffer = deletate?.currentFrameScalledImage else { return }
        guard let image = CGImage.create(from: vImageBuffer) else { return }
        
        func featureprintObservationForImage(image: CGImage) -> VNFeaturePrintObservation? {
            let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, options: [:])
            let request = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest()
            do {
                try requestHandler.perform([request])
                return request.results?.first as? VNFeaturePrintObservation
            } catch {
                print("Vision error: \(error)")
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        guard let imageFingerprint = featureprintObservationForImage(image: image) else { return }
        guard compareScanningImages(current: imageFingerprint, last: lastScanningImageFingerprint) else { return }
        print("SCANN \(Date())")
        lastScanningImageFingerprint = featureprintObservationForImage(image: image)
        executeScanning(on: image) { [weak self] in
            self?.scanningInProgress = false
        }
    }
```

Tested on older iPhone - as expected this causes some frame drops on camera preview. So I need a faster algorithm

Comment: "What would be the best solution for this?" What makes one solution the best of all? Show one solution in code that you have so that we can tell whether or not there is a more efficient approach.

Comment: Solving this sort of problem is not trivial. You're basically asking about computer vision. You might look at using the OpenCV library. The more you know about the images you are comparing, the more you can tailor your comparison algorithm to the data. Are the images always of the same subject? Are there geometric shapes in the image that you can look for? In the context you are working in, do you have an idea of what constitutes "a lot" being changed? Are you looking for changes in shape? Position? Brightness? Color?

Comment: The app I'm working on is a AR app that displays videos on the pictures. The problem is that my database contains about 1000 pictures, so ARKit alone can't handle them. Instead - when ARKit doesn't detect anything Im using Vuforia WebService if it can see anything on the frame, and then I can download for example up to 25 images at the time for ARKit to track. I want to limit the number of requests sent to Vuforia Web Service - if on one frame it didn't detect any target, then I would like to send another request only if for example user moves camera a lot, or added a picture in front of cam.